# unexpected double ampersand/pipe behavior when chaining batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

My foo.bat file:

```
exit /b 1
```

What I execute in a cmd prompt:

```
foo.bat && echo "OK"
```

Result:

```
exit /b 1
"OK"
```

Yet, when I use double pipe, the echo doesn't occur:

```
foo.bat || echo "OK"
```

Result:

```
exit /b 1
```

This is the exact opposite behavior of what I expect && and || to do.  See https://ss64.com/nt/call.html, where it says:

> commandA && commandB      Run commandA, if it succeeds then run commandB

and

> commandA || commandB      Run commandA, if it fails then run commandB

Am I losing my mind?  What am I missing here?

Comment: `call foo.bat && echo ok || echo fail` works (I know, that's no explanation for the described behavior because - well I don't have one. I'm as surprised as you are)

Comment: You have to use `call` to run `foo.bat` and to get its exit code, which can be got by `&&` and/or `||`; otherwise, execution control does not (really) go back to the calling script; but since the complete command line (with `&&` or `||`) has already been read and parsed, it seems to be fully executed, but not using the exit code returned by `foo.bat` but only from *starting* it, which obviously succeeded...

Comment: @aschipfl - Nope - `&&` and `||` respond to the return code of the last command executed in the script. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`||` and `&&` respond to the return code of the previous command (the last executed command on the left). All programs exit with an error code, regardless of context.

`EXIT /B 1` sets the batch ERRORLEVEL, which is strictly a cmd.exe concept.

The return code and ERRORLEVEL are ***not*** the same thing!

When a batch file is executed, the exiting ERRORLEVEL is only returned as the return code if the batch file was executed via `CALL`.

When a batch file is executed without CALL, `&&` and `||` respond to the last command executed within the script.

`EXIT /B 1` sets ERRORLEVEL to 1, but the command executed successfully, so the return code is 0.

When `CALL` is used, the CALL command looks at the ERRORLEVEL after the script terminates, and sets the return code to the ERRORLEVEL.

Answer (score 0):

`foo.bat` ran successfully. It set errorlevel to 1. Hence `&&` / `||` shows results for `success`.

if `oof.bat` does not exist, then it cannot run successfully. It did not set errorlevel to 1 (sets `9009` on my machine.) Hence `&&` / `||` shows results for `fail`.

Consider `echoerrorlevel.bat`:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO errorlevel=%ERRORLEVEL%
```

then `foo&echoerrorlevel` shows `errorlevel` returned by `foo`, but `oof&echoerrorlevel` shows `errorlevel` 9009 after a complaint that can be suppressed by the standard `2>nul`

Comment: Right. I sometimes forget, that `&&` and `||` doesn't evaluate the errorlevel, but the success/fail of a command - which is not always the same.

Comment: You almost got it. True that when oof.bat doesn't exist, the `||` is fired by the 9009 error. But `||` can also fire if foo.bat exists if the last command executed by foo returned an error. `&&` and `||` always respond to the last command that was executed. (If redirection fails, then that can become the last "command") See my answer.